# Color Coming out of the specified area of Linear Layout

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

[Refer the image to understand it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdNEX.png)    I have been building a linear layout with rounded corners. The radius assigned to the corners is 15 dp. Still the White color is showing out of the corners. A picture has been attached for help.

```
Main XML File:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/bottom_menu_shape"
>
</LinearLayout>


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >

            <corners
                android:topLeftRadius="25dp"
                android:topRightRadius="25dp"
                />
            <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#00249C"/>

        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

The code is working but the white color is coming in the shape of rectangle.
Is there any way to have the white color just inside the rounded corners of the layout.

```
Expecting: White color inside the rounded layout
Actual Output: White color in rectangle shape coming out of the layout.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a layer-list by placing another layer behind the rectangle with rounded corners and set it to whatever color you desire.  I used dark red here for demonstration purposes

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item>

    <shape
        android:shape="rectangle"
        android:tint="@android:color/holo_red_dark">
    </shape>

</item>


<item >
    <shape android:shape="rectangle"
        android:tint="@android:color/white">

        <corners
            android:topLeftRadius="25dp"
            android:topRightRadius="25dp"
            />
        <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#00249C"/>

    </shape>
</item>
```

[image]